# SSL and .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I am developing a website that has an SSL Certificate applied to it! Now I want people visiting the site with https and not http.

I have been able to achieve this with...

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}    off
  RewriteRule   (.*)     https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</ifModule>
```

But I would like it to default to www.mysite.co.uk and not mysite.co.uk automatically! I was also able to remove the index.php by using this...

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

But just stumped on the www. bit! Any help is gratefully appreciated!
- Phillip Dews

Comment: so why not `rewriterule .* https://www.mysite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}`? `%{HTTP_HOST}` is literally the name provided by the user and sent by teh browser in the `Host:` header.

Comment: So, this will help you - RewriteRule   (.*) https ://www.mysite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: Hi @mark-b,
I did try that but kept getting a 500 internal server error!

Answer (score 1):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk
    RewriteRule   (.*)     https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}    off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk
    RewriteRule   (.*)     https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</ifModule>
```

This will make sure that you always have www and https in the URL. You can test it at: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Hi @neo, That is perfect and just what I needed. Many thanks!
- Phillip Dews